# What inputs does an iPad have?

Tags: ipad, hardware

What possible ways of reading input does an iPad have? Right now I can think of:

- Touch screen (multitouch I believe?)
- Camera
- Brightness adjuster (How does that work? Could it be used for
  anything other than the brightness adjustment?)
- Orientation detector
- The standard input buttons

Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

Besides the obvious **USB / Lightning connector** and the **WiFi / Cellular / Bluetooth** technology, the iPad has:

- Volume up / down switch
- Silent / Screen rotation lock
- Microphone
- Built-in speaker
- The *gyroscope*
- The *accelerometer*
- The ambient light sensor
- Micro-SIM card try
- Facetime / iSight camera
- Multi-Touch display

Bear in mind that these are for the latest version.

Comment: There is also the GPS on the Cellular version.